# c++ identity operand for products

Tags: generics, c++11

There is a generic way to get the identity operand for a sum. If `T` is a type, then `T{}` returns this operand. `T{} + T{} == T{}` example: `int{} == 0`

Is there also a generic way in C++ to the the identity operand for products?

Comment: "*If T is a type, then T{} returns this operand. T{} + T{} == T{} example:*" There is *nothing* in C++ that requires this for any particular implementation of default construction or `operator+`. Or `operator==`, for that matter. If this is true, it is only because the implementer of `T` *made* it true.

Comment: I doubt such a concept exists, but it would be easy to implement some traits for this, with the default implementation returning `T{1}` but specializations could do something different.

Comment: @MvG, exactly, that was my expectation that there would be some hidden trait in boost for this purpose. But if a Math-Guy like you does not no it probably does not exist. As you say it is easy to do but it would be ugly to do if already existent in some fairly standard library.

Answer (score 0):

The notation `T{}` probably renders [value-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). To get a what you are asking for, you would need to implement your class so that the default constructor return the identity for the product operator (which implies that the identity `T{} + T{} == T{}` won't be true anymore).